# Ant Design: DatePicker Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, ant-design-pro

```
    <Form>
        <Form.Item label="Status">
            <Select
                placeholder= "Select Status"
                value={this.props.clearValues.status}
                showSearch
                onChange={(e) => this.props.handleDropdown(e, "status")}
                >
                    <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
                    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
                    <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
            </Select>
        </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

I have select box and I am using `placeholder="Select Status"` and `value={ this.props.clearValues.status }` but the problem is when I use both placeholder and value, the placeholder does not appear but when I delete a value, placeholder shows up. (this value is sent from parent component). 
 I want to use both but how?

Comment: This is basically the placeholder functionality. It appears when the value is not set/deleted by the user. Note: antd will recognize empty string as actual value so you need to use for example undefined as 'empty value' for placeholder to appear.

Comment: initially my value is empty.

Comment: your initial value is empty string?

Comment: yes sir initially its an empty string

Comment: Well, as I said before antd recognize empty string as actual value which blocks placeholder to appear. Try to use `undefined` as "empty" value for Select component.